# How could I optimize the following piece of code?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

```
$project_query= $db->query("SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id='$task_info->project_id'");
$project_info = $project_query->fetch_object();
$admins_array = $project_info->admins_array;

$admins = unserialize($admins_array);
$is_admin = false;
foreach($admins as $value) {
if($value == $_SESSION['username']) { $is_admin = true; }
}
```

I have the following code that checks if the currently logged user's username is contained in a serialized array that is stored in a mysql table row. How would I go about optimizing it for maximum performance?

Comment: Why do you want to optimize these particular lines?

Comment: I think that there may be a more efficient way of getting the job done

Comment: @Sam: first optimization rule: measure. Take profiler and measure if it's slow. Second optimization rule: optimize only what is slow.

Comment: @Chris Hayes: "massive security flaw" --- you are overdramatizing. It's an integer that is retrieved from DB. Even though I agree it's a bad code - but it's not vulnerable. If you are going to discuss it, please start it with some proofs that you may exploit it, otherwise don't waste your time.

Comment: @zerkms He's dropping a potentially unsanitized variable directly into his query. If he's doing it in this one place, he's almost certainly doing it other places. Yes, it's a big flaw.

Comment: @Chris Hayes: "he's almost certainly doing it other place" --- I see, it's called guessing. "**Right now you have**" --- you probably should have said that "you probably have issues somewhere else". Right now your comment looks like you can exploit **this particular code** which you obviously cannot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57616/discussion-between-zerkms-and-chris-hayes).

Comment: @Chris Hayes: "Right now I could cause this particular code to run" --- you cannot, please don't confuse newbies. If you really could - I'm really interested in looking at that. May be something I can learn from you.

Comment: @Chris Hayes: not surprising it didn't come to some real when I asked about details :-) /me sighs, not a day to learn something about extra-sql-injection-skills from a real master :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) if changing your db structure is a possibility, I suggest storing the serialized values in a separate table

`project_admins (project_id, user_id)` with a unique index on `(project_id,user_id)`

Then you can quickly determine whether a user is an admin of a project

```
SELECT 1 from project_admins where project_id = x and user_id = y
```

2) if you're stuck with storing serialized data in the db I suggest storing the serialized array indexed by `username`
so you can search it in constant time

i.e.

```
$is_admin = array_key_exists($_SESSION['username'],$admins);
```

3) if you can not index the admins array by username, you can minimally optimize your loop by adding a break statement once you find a match

```
foreach($admins as $value) {
    if($value == $_SESSION['username']) { 
        $is_admin = true; 
        break; // match found no need to check remaining values
    }
}
```

Actually in this case you're probably better off using `in_array`

```
$is_admin = in_array($_SESSION['username'],$admins);
```

Comment: "so you can search it in constant time" --- until you have tens of thousands elements it doesn't change anything from performance point of view.

Answer (score 0):

If it's optimization in terms of speed, then I would suggest performing the login in SQL.

It would require you to change your table structure to a more normalised state by switching from serialised strings into separate related entities.

Comment: The question is not about authentication, but authorization.

Comment: "maximum performance" is hardly a statement I would make about security.

Comment: I did not say anything about performance or security. My comment was about the fact that OP is asking about authorization whereas your answer is about authentication. There is a difference between these two.

Comment: I am under the impression that the OP is looking for ways to improve the performance of his code. My suggestion makes no improvement to the OP's authorisation method but I would indeed improve the performance of his code.

Comment: you are confusing authorization and authentication. Your current answer is about authentication, but OP has authorization-related code.

Comment: What does the speed of your code have to do with authorization??

Comment: oh my god. "then I would suggest performing the login in SQL" --- OP's code has **NOTHING TO DO** with logging in (authentication). How the hell improving login process performance could improve OPs code if it **DOES NOT HAVE** logging in here?

Comment: Do you think login is the only thing that uses SQL!? Performing the query in SQL would be faster than de serialising a string and looping through it's values. It could take place in tim buk to for all I care, but in the case of the OP it is in the SQL.

Comment: "Do you think login is the only thing that uses SQL" --- I don't. I'm just commenting your answer, which at the moment is irrelevant to the question, since OP does not have even a single note about logging in facilities in their code. Why do you think they even use SQL for log in, not LDAP?

Comment: I have read it. I see: 1. the question is about authorization, your answer is about authentication 2. I don't see anything that could make you thinking authentication is made using sql. But anyway, good luck with your answer, I'm off telling obvious things 3 times in a row.

Comment: 1. The question is not about authorization. Please explain to me in detail how you came to that assumption?

Comment: `foreach($admins as $value) {
if($value == $_SESSION['username']) { $is_admin = true; }
}` --- what do you think this code does?

Comment: It provides you with a boolean flag to perform some logic. My answer would completely remove those lines all together by returning the boolean value from SQL. Performance. Improved.

Comment: "It provides you with a boolean flag to perform some logic" --- guess how it's called: *authorization*. "My answer would completely remove those lines all together" --- your answer mentioned authentication. Sorry, I cannot realize how one could tell they are mentioning apple whereas it's clearly specified "orange" in the answer. PS: I understand that terminology is hard, but please spend some time and find out the difference between authentication and authorization. And finally remove "login" word from your answer, it's confusing and irrelevant.

Comment: Please ignore zerkms, he seems to be completely incapable of reading context clues and takes everything 100% literally. I find nothing confusing in this answer.